# String find and replace method optimization

Tags: java, error-handling, hash-map

I am trying to find a specific header string from different Maps (`LEDES1998Bheaders`, `LEDES98BIheaders` and `LEDES98BI_V2headers`) in an `errorMessage` depends on the parcel type and if the `errorMessage` has the specific header string I need to replace it with the corresponding value.

```
public class ErrorMessageConverter {

    private static Map<String, String> LEDES1998Bheaders = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<String, String> LEDES98BIheaders = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<String, String> LEDES98BI_V2headers = new HashMap<>();

    static {
                LEDES1998Bheaders.put("(\\binv_date\\b|\\bINVOICE DATE\\b)", "INVOICE DATE");
    LEDES1998Bheaders.put("\\binv_id\\b", "INVOICE NUMBER");
    LEDES1998Bheaders.put("\\bcl_id\\b", "CLIENT ID");
    LEDES1998Bheaders.put("\\blf_matter_id\\b", "LAW FIRM MATTER ID");
    LEDES1998Bheaders.put("\\bUNITS\\b", "LINE ITEM NUMBER OF UNITS");
    LEDES1998Bheaders.put("(\\bBaseRate\\b|\\bRate\\b|\\btk_rate\\b)", "LINE ITEM UNIT COST");

    LEDES98BIheaders.put("\\blf_address/address_info/address_1\\b", "LAW FIRM ADDRESS 1");
    LEDES98BIheaders.put("\\blf_address/address_info/city\\b", "LAW FIRM CITY");
    LEDES98BIheaders.put("\\btax_rate\\b", "LINE ITEM TAX RATE");
    LEDES98BIheaders.put("\\btax_on_charge\\b", "LINE ITEM TAX TOTAL");
    LEDES98BIheaders.put("\\btax_type\\b", "LINE ITEM TAX TYPE");

    LEDES98BI_V2headers.put("\\binv_reported_tax_total\\b", "INVOICE REPORTED TAX TOTAL");
    LEDES98BI_V2headers.put("\\binv_reported_tax_currency\\b", "INVOICE TAX CURRENCY");

    }

    public static String toUserFriendlyErrorMessage(String parcelType, String message) {

        if (parcelType.equals("LEDES1998B")) {
            return updateErrorMessage(message, LEDES1998Bheaders);
        } 
       else if (parcelType.equals("LEDES98BI")) {
            message = updateErrorMessage(message, LEDES1998Bheaders);
            return updateErrorMessage(message, LEDES98BIheaders);
        } 
       else if (parcelType.equals("LEDES98BI V2")) {
            message = updateErrorMessage(message, LEDES1998Bheaders);
            message = updateErrorMessage(message, LEDES98BIheaders);
            return updateErrorMessage(message, LEDES98BI_V2headers);
        }
        return message;

    }

    private static String updateErrorMessage(String msg, Map<String, String> invHeaders) {
        Pattern pattern;
    for (String key : invHeaders.keySet()) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(key);
        if (pattern.matcher(msg).find()) {
            msg = msg.replaceAll(key, invHeaders.get(key));
        }
    }
    return msg;
    }
}
```

Below are couple of sample error messages:

```
String errorMesage1 = "Line 3 : Could not parse inv_date value" 
String errorMesage2 = "Line : 1 BaseRate is a required field"
```

Can this method simplified further in java 8 using filters/lambda expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fairly effective, but it could be a bunch more efficient if you rearrange the code a bit, do some pre-processing, and reduce your run-time checks. Let's go through that in order....

I recommend a 'set up' stage to your code. Consider an ideal situation at runtime, the code would look something like:

```
public static String toUserFriendlyErrorMessage(String parcelType, String message) {

    for (Rule rule : getRules(parcelType)) {
        message = rule.process(message);
    }
    return message;
}
```

That would be a neat solution, where you have a bunch of rules that you know apply to the messages of a particular type, and that you can then just apply whichever ones are appropriate. That would be the most efficient at use-time too.

How would you implement that? Using some pre-processing, of course, and a new `Rule` class.

This preprocessing is key, and the features you should look for here are:

1. the rules are sorted at pre-process time.
2. some rules are in multiple sets of operations.
3. `Pattern` instances are compiled just once, not at use-time.

Your rules are convenient in the sense that the `parcelType` values seems to have an 'extension' type system:

- `LEDES1998B` is rules `LEDES1998Bheaders`
- `LEDES98BI` is the same as `LEDES1998B` plus the rules in `LEDES98BIheaders`
- `LEDES98BI V2` is the same as `LEDES98BI` (and thus `LEDES1998B`) but also includes `LEDES98BI_V2headers`

How would I recommend preprocessing things?

```
private static final class Rule {
    private final Pattern key;
    private final String replacement;

    Rule(String search, String rep) {
        key = Pattern.compile(search);
        replacement = Matcher.quoteReplacement(rep);
    }

    String process(String msg) {
        return key.matcher(msg).replaceAll(replacement);
    }
}
```

So, that rule class is simple enough... how to add them together?

```
private static final Map<String, Rule[]> RULE_MAP = buildMap();

private static final Map<String, Rule[]> buildMap() {
    Map<String, Rule[]> result = new HashMap<>();
    List<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<>();

    addRules(rules, LEDES1998Bheaders);
    result.put("LEDES1998B", rules.toArray(new Rule[rules.size()]));

    addRules(rules, LEDES98BIheaders);
    result.put("LEDES98BI", rules.toArray(new Rule[rules.size()]));

    addRules(rules, LEDES98BI_V2headers);
    result.put("LEDES98BI V2", rules.toArray(new Rule[rules.size()]));

    return result;
}

private static final void addRules(List<Rule> target, Map<String,String> sources) {
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> me : sources.entrySet()) {
        target.add(new Rule(me.getKey(), me.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Now, your last part is the `getRules` method:

```
private static final Rule[] getRules(String parcelType) {
    Rule[] rules = RULE_MAP.get(parcelType);
    if (rules == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No rules set for type " + parcelType);
    }
    return rules;
}
```

Now your code should go smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution, I really appreciate it. But if the parceltype is `LEDES98BI` I need to check both `LEDES1998Bheaders` and `LEDES98BIheaders`, and if the parceltype is `LEDES98BI V2` I need to check all the three maps `LEDES1998Bheaders`, `LEDES98BIheaders` and `LEDES98BI_V2headers` I think your solution checks only the specific Rules from specific map as per the `parcelType`

Comment: @RanPaul - I think you will find that it does not clear the `rules` array after loading the `LEDES1998Bheaders` rules, so they are also in the rules that are added to when the `LEDES98BIheaders` are processed

Comment: The order-of-processing is significant so that each time you `addRules(...)` you are really adding *more* rules, so you are doing the same rules as the previous rule set, plus the new rules. Thus when you call `result.put("LEDES98BI V2", rules.toArray(new Rule[rules.size()]);` you will be adding *all* the rules for all rulesets when you process parcelType `LEDES98BI_V2headers`

Comment: I just tried your solution and its not updating error messages in getRules method am getting rules value as `org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array`

Comment: I have been known to break things before, but my code could not have caused eclipse exceptions like that. Consider doing a 'clean' on your eclipse project.... you can compile everything successfully, right?

Comment: I've tried `eclipse clean`, `maven clean` and `clean install` but nothing fixed the issue. Am still getting getting `rules` value as `org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array`

Comment: Are you able to update the messages for diff parcelTypes on your machine?

Comment: @RanPaul - yes, and on Ideone too: http://ideone.com/o2Y7Dy - there is a few places missing a close-parenthesis... let me update my answer - but this will not fix your problem.